# Tables are cut and the appendix header is in different page

Tags: tables, appendix

As can be seen there the second table of the appendix is cut. In addition, the Appendix header is in the previous page. Here is the result:[image]

Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hspace{1em}$\triangleright$ #1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\newpage

    \appendix

    \section{\\Appendix: Accusdffssdfaasdfdfsa fasddsf sfdadfs (3 digit format)} \label{appendix:AppendixA} 
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=1.3] 
                S[table-format=1.4] c c c }
            \toprule
            \thead{Dataset}  
            &   {\thead{fasddfs\\ of fsdasdf}} 
            &   {\thead{fasdfs J4d8\\ fsdf}}
            &   {\thead{fsd fsd\\ fsdf}}
             &  \thead{fsdfs}
            &   \thead{P-sfdfs}
            &   \thead{fsdfsd  \\ Size }                 \\ 
            \midrule
            Poker & 32  & 0.632 & 0.592 & -0.04  &  \textless0.001 & 100000  \\ 
            Poker & 64  & 0.594 & 0.566 & -0.028 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\ 
            Poker & 128 & 0.537 & 0.533 & -0.003 &  0.051 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            Poker & 256  & 0.499 & 0.521 & 0.022  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            Poker & 512  & 0.499 & 0.525 & 0.026  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            Poker & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.484 & -0.014 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY & 32   & 0.543 & 0.788 & 0.245   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 64   & 0.543 & 0.786 & 0.242   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 128  & 0.543 & 0.783 & 0.239   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY &  256 & 0.543 & 0.778 & 0.234  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            SUSY &  512 & 0.543 & 0.772 & 0.228  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            SUSY &  1024& 0.781 & 0.767 & -0.013 &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  32  & 0.781 & 0.767 & -2E-05 &  0.281    & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 &  0.137    & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -6E-05 &  0.144    & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -4E-05  &  0.327 & 50000  \\
            RLCP &  512 & 1     & 1     &    0    &  -     & 10000  \\
            RLCP &  1024& 1     & 0.999 & -0.0002 &  0.078 & 10000  \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   32  & 0.998 & 0.993 & -0.005  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   64  & 0.997 & 0.997 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   128 & 0.996 & 0.995 & -0.001  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   256 & 0.995 & 0.993 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   512 & 0.988 & 0.987 & -0.001 &  0.036   & 50000  \\
            KDD CUP &   1024& 0.984 & 0.984 & 1E-04  &  0.477   & 10000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\newpage
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=1.3] 
                S[table-format=1.4] c c c}
            \toprule
            \thead{Dataset}  
            &   {\thead{fdsfds\\ of fsdfs}} 
            &   {\thead{fsd fsd\\ fsd}}
            &   {\thead{fsd fsd\\ fsd}}
             &  \thead{fsdfsd}
             &   \thead{P-fsds}
            &   \thead{fsdfds  \\ Size }                  \\ 
            \midrule
            Poker & 32  & 0.563 & 0.549 & -0.014 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
            Poker & 64  & 0.550 & 0.542 & -0.007 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
            Poker & 128 & 0.536 & 0.533 & -0.003 & 0.096    & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            Poker & 256  & 0.521 & 0.504 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            Poker & 512  & 0.499 & 0.486 & -0.013 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            Poker & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.471 & -0.027 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY & 32   & 0.791 & 0.784 & -0.006 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 64   & 0.787 & 0.779 & -0.008 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 128  & 0.781 & 0.769 & -0.012 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY &  256 & 0.781 & 0.765 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            SUSY &  512 & 0.781 & 0.756 & -0.025 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            SUSY &  1024& 0.781 & 0.751 & -0.03  &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  32  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 & 0.222 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 50000  \\
            RLCP &  512 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-04  & 0.352    & 10000  \\
            RLCP &  1024& 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.0003  & 0.182    & 10000  \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   32  & 0.992 & 0.990 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   64  & 0.987 & 0.987 & 0      & 0.5      & 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   128 & 0.987 & 0.987 & -8E-05 & 0.455    & 150000 \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   256 & 0.987 & 0.987 & 2E-05  & 0.488 & 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   512 & 0.984 & 0.984 & 0.0003 & 0.431 & 50000  \\
            KDD CUP &   1024& 0.984 & 0.998 & 0.0139 &\textless0.001& 10000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `table` environment can not contain a pagebreak. Therefore use an own `table` environment for every `tabular` in your example code or even better, entirely remove the `table` environment

Comment: Please also clean up your preamble. Several lines are repeated multiple times, such as `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`. Also keep in ind the load order of packages: `hyperref` should generally (with a few exceptions) be loaded last.

Comment: (i) clean up your document preamble of all twice or third time repeated definitions. (ii) your table is to long that csn be fit on one page. Consider to split itinto two parts or may be better to consider of use a `longtable`.

Comment: Please do not use white pencil to write over your image, you are already using dummy text so why do you make it so hard to see, if your result and our result is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you main issue here is that you are using an environment `table` which makes your table floating.

Please see the following MWE where I commented out environment `table` for the first tabular. See also that I deleted a lot of packages not related to this issue and I deleted double used commands ... Please see that I added option `showframe` to package `geometry` to visualize the used typing area and margins ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[%
  a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\begin{document}

\appendix

\section{Appendix: Accusdffssdfaasdfdfsa fasddsf sfdadfs (3 digit format)}
\label{appendix:AppendixA} 
%\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=1.3] 
                S[table-format=1.4] c c c }
            \toprule
            \thead{Dataset}  
            &   {\thead{fasddfs\\ of fsdasdf}} 
            &   {\thead{fasdfs J4d8\\ fsdf}}
            &   {\thead{fsd fsd\\ fsdf}}
             &  \thead{fsdfs}
            &   \thead{P-sfdfs}
            &   \thead{fsdfsd  \\ Size }                 \\ 
            \midrule
            Poker & 32  & 0.632 & 0.592 & -0.04  &  \textless0.001 & 100000  \\ 
            Poker & 64  & 0.594 & 0.566 & -0.028 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\ 
            Poker & 128 & 0.537 & 0.533 & -0.003 &  0.051 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            Poker & 256  & 0.499 & 0.521 & 0.022  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            Poker & 512  & 0.499 & 0.525 & 0.026  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            Poker & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.484 & -0.014 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY & 32   & 0.543 & 0.788 & 0.245   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 64   & 0.543 & 0.786 & 0.242   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 128  & 0.543 & 0.783 & 0.239   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY &  256 & 0.543 & 0.778 & 0.234  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            SUSY &  512 & 0.543 & 0.772 & 0.228  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            SUSY &  1024& 0.781 & 0.767 & -0.013 &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  32  & 0.781 & 0.767 & -2E-05 &  0.281    & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 &  0.137    & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -6E-05 &  0.144    & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -4E-05  &  0.327 & 50000  \\
            RLCP &  512 & 1     & 1     &    0    &  -     & 10000  \\
            RLCP &  1024& 1     & 0.999 & -0.0002 &  0.078 & 10000  \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   32  & 0.998 & 0.993 & -0.005  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   64  & 0.997 & 0.997 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   128 & 0.996 & 0.995 & -0.001  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   256 & 0.995 & 0.993 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   512 & 0.988 & 0.987 & -0.001 &  0.036   & 50000  \\
            KDD CUP &   1024& 0.984 & 0.984 & 1E-04  &  0.477   & 10000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                S[table-format=1.3] 
                S[table-format=1.4] c c c}
            \toprule
            \thead{Dataset}  
            &   {\thead{fdsfds\\ of fsdfs}} 
            &   {\thead{fsd fsd\\ fsd}}
            &   {\thead{fsd fsd\\ fsd}}
             &  \thead{fsdfsd}
             &   \thead{P-fsds}
            &   \thead{fsdfds  \\ Size }                  \\ 
            \midrule
            Poker & 32  & 0.563 & 0.549 & -0.014 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
            Poker & 64  & 0.550 & 0.542 & -0.007 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
            Poker & 128 & 0.536 & 0.533 & -0.003 & 0.096    & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            Poker & 256  & 0.521 & 0.504 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            Poker & 512  & 0.499 & 0.486 & -0.013 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            Poker & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.471 & -0.027 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY & 32   & 0.791 & 0.784 & -0.006 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 64   & 0.787 & 0.779 & -0.008 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            SUSY & 128  & 0.781 & 0.769 & -0.012 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
            \addlinespace
            SUSY &  256 & 0.781 & 0.765 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            SUSY &  512 & 0.781 & 0.756 & -0.025 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            SUSY &  1024& 0.781 & 0.751 & -0.03  &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  32  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
            RLCP &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 & 0.222 & 100000 \\
            \addlinespace
            RLCP &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 50000  \\
            RLCP &  512 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-04  & 0.352    & 10000  \\
            RLCP &  1024& 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.0003  & 0.182    & 10000  \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   32  & 0.992 & 0.990 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   64  & 0.987 & 0.987 & 0      & 0.5      & 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   128 & 0.987 & 0.987 & -8E-05 & 0.455    & 150000 \\
            \addlinespace
            KDD CUP &   256 & 0.987 & 0.987 & 2E-05  & 0.488 & 150000 \\
            KDD CUP &   512 & 0.984 & 0.984 & 0.0003 & 0.431 & 50000  \\
            KDD CUP &   1024& 0.984 & 0.998 & 0.0139 &\textless0.001& 10000  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

resulting in this two pages:

[image: page One]

and page two:

[image: page two]

As you can see table 1 is now under the section headline and table 2 on the next page ...

If you do not want to add an table title to your tabulars you can completly omit environment `table` ... If you have longer tables you need to use `longtable` to get tables be able to span more than one page ...