# What should I do to prevent equations and tables from overflowing over the page margins (downwards)?

Tags: tables, equations, margins

Nothing special here, just want to know about a good way to get long equations that start at the end of the page to be automatically started on a new page.

Also what should I do with long tables? Do I have to manually cut the table in half? Or is there a package that auto cuts the table and places a new header for the second table on the second page?

I saw this [Tables are cut and the appendix header is in different page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504231/tables-are-cut-and-the-appendix-header-is-in-different-page), but was very confused (I just started using LaTeX)

Here's an example:

[image: Equation overflow]
[image: table overflow]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you consulted the posting [Is it possible to pagebreak aligned equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51682/5001) If you're using a `tabular` environment to typeset the two columns of equations, do familiarize yourself with the [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package and its eponymous environment.

Comment: BTW, the bottom of the text area should align with the last baseline, so descenders (gjpqy) will go below the line.

Comment: Thanks @Mico I will use longtable.